# Remove list of tables and list of figures from table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have seen some similar questions in the forums, but did not understand the answers provided.

Is there a way I could remove lists of tables and figures from my toc?

Here is my a M.W.E similar to the original document.

```
\documentclass{abntex2}

\begin{document}

{...}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need all those packages to reproduce the problem? If so, just drop `lipsum` - problem solved. This can't be something you need in your document and you aren't using it in the example, either.

Comment: @cfr sorry. There are more in my document. I was not sure what was causing it, so I kept some of them to show the problem.

Comment: @cfr is does not solves the problem in the original file.

Comment: Your example should demonstrate the problem. Find out if they are causing it by removing them. Put them back if the problem goes away. Of course it doesn't solve the problem. That's my point.

Comment: an `abntex2` template is **not** a MWE... Just try the **basic**: `\documentclass{abntex2} \begin{document} ... \end{document}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abntex2` is a class that loads `memoir` as base class, which in turn provides starred versions of `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`, so using those macros removes the listing of the `\listof...` in the `ToC`.

The manual of `abntex2` explicitly mentions `\listoffigures*` etc. on page 31 (however, in Portuguese)

[image]

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,               
    openright,          
    oneside,        
    a4paper,                    
    english,
    brazil,         
    ]{abntex2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}        
\makeatother
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}             
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}    
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{flafter} 


\makeindex

\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark[0]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents*

\renewcommand*\listfigurename{Lista de figuras}
\listoffigures*

\listoftables*
\cleardoublepage

\end{document}
```